# How to pass from String to Char

Tags: java, string, unicode, char

I have the following:

```
String a = "\u0043";
```

I know that is an Unicode char and I want to obtain its ASCII value.
This is an example of I want to do:

```
String A = "A";
```

is

```
int ascii = 65;
```

or:

```
String A = "\u0043";
```

is

```
int ascii = 67;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] and earn a badge! Also read our [ask] page and get ideas on how to improve this question, then come back and [edit] your question to make it better

Comment: `"'\u0043'"` isn't a character, it's a string of length 3 (apostrophe + letter C + apostrophe).

Comment: I mean '\u0043' as a string

Comment: What language??

Comment: I am using Java

Answer (score 1):

```java
String A ="\u0043"; //Letter C
int c = A.charAt(0);
System.out.println(c); //Prints 67
        
String B = "A"; //Letter A
int a = B.charAt(0);
System.out.println(a); //Prints 65
```